# CDI @ConversationScoped and JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, redirect, cdi

Doing a POST and then redirect is a very common scenario in web applications.  CDI `@ConversationScoped` plays well with JSF to preserve state between POST and redirect.

But, can I use CDI `@ConversationScoped` with JSP?

If not, what is the alternate solution for JSP?

Please note:

(1) I don't want to use HTTPSession to save state for obvious reasons.

(2) I don't want to save my sensitive data such as passwords in client side (in Cookies or URLs) for this purpose.

Comment: Why are you asking this specifically in JSP context? You know that writing Java code straight in a JSP is a very bad practice? Don't you actually mean or rather want to use CDI in *Servlets*?

Comment: My intention is to have a \@Named \@ConversationScoped bean, and to refer the bean properties using EL in JSP pages, something like ${myBean.email}

Comment: You seem to never have heard of servlets and incorrectly blindly focusing on JSP as the place to perform business logic. Please start at our servlets wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info You can easily use `@Inject` in servlets the usual way.

Comment: Actually I only use JSP to get user input, here is the actual scenario: I have two page form. After the user has filled the 1st page, and during the time when the user is in the 2nd page, I need a place to keep the data from the 1st page, that’s it. I can put it in the session, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conversation Scope in CDI 1.0 is strictly tied to JSF, it will not work in JSPs in CDI 1.0, however it should work fine in CDI 1.1 which is part of Java EE 7.

Comment: Great news! This is a missing part in JSP which is available in JSF.